# Border around divs when viewing on mobile device

Tags: android, html, ios, css

My website homepage is nearing completing, however I have small but noticeable borders/outlines appearing when I view the page on a mobile device. This does not occur on computers (that I am aware of) so you will need a iPhone/tablet/smartphone to see the problem. [Link to website](http://www.ittdsnowsports.ie)

I have seen questions of this nature, and I have tried the negative margin-top CSS on the cloud image specifically, but to no avail.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2UfMmDjLxJvNDBraHRpbzc2eGs/edit?usp=sharing)

The lines disappear once zoomed in enough on the webpage itself, but they've started to irritate me when I see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are pixel errors when view in mobile causing that very small line you're seeing.  It's due to your 'wrapper' div's background being white.  Since the 'intro' div is over top of this and has a color that matches the website's background, the white background of the 'wrapper' div shows through when there is some pixel error.

I would try splitting the top part of the wrapper into another child div and coloring it's background white, leaving the entire wrapper div without a background color.

Comment: I used your technique and it helped a lot, however it was still affecting the page at certain zoom percentages. Think I fixed this by using `margin-bottom` as a negative number with certain divs. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit old this post, but this problem doesn't have any good solution yet today. The best workaround is to place a *-1px margin and 1px padding*, as you can see on this codepen when viewed from chrome mobile:

https://codepen.io/bertri/pen/aaGmGW

```
<div style="background: white; font-size: 72px">First elem</div>
<div style="background: white; font-size: 72px">Has margin</div>
<div style="background: white; font-size: 72px; margin-top: -1px; padding-top: 1px">Hack to solve margin</div>
```